# Sentry upgrade from 21.1.0 -> 23.8.0?

Tags: devops, sentry

I am using Sentry 21.1.0 and I want to upgrade to 23.8.0 and there is no proper guide to upgrade Sentry. It would be great if anyone would let me know how to do it.

According to Sentry docs the upgrade should be done one version after another, but that would be time consuming process and causing issues and there are some versions between 21.1.0 & 23.8.0.